# Catching the url path following a python cgi script?

Tags: python, url, cgi

It's better if I do an example to explain my question:

Filename of cgi script: 'awesome'
URL: http://omgpython.com/awesome
'awesome' script runs normally.

I append a 'fake' path: '/omg/so/fake'
URL: http://omgpython.com/awesome/omg/so/fake'

'awesome' script runs normally without any errors, but is it possible to catch the 'fake' path within 'awesome'?

I'm trying to clean the URL by not using URL params.

Comment: Please add some more details about which frameworks and environment you're running in.

Comment: @chmullig 

I'm not running any frameworks. It's a simple cgi-script call.
I'm a newbie, so I'm not sure what environment information you want. I'm not running it under mod_wsgi if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `os.environ['PATH_INFO']`. In the second example it will contain "`/omg/so/fake`".

Comment: And then what, what is to be done with it? How can it be used? Could you please answer a bit more comprehensively? This may not be as obvious to me as it is to you.

Comment: Either amend your answer, or please answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49928262/4909087), it was asked as a follow up to this.