# How to hide a url with os.environ['PATH_INFO']

Tags: python, url, server, cgi

I am trying to make a "fake" url with a cgi script, similar to what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939067/catching-the-url-path-following-a-python-cgi-script) question asks for, the accepted answer seems to suggest a solution using `os.environ['PATH_INFO']`, however nowhere can I find an example on how to use it.

I have tried this (located at `192.168.0.8/path/index.py`) so far:

```
#!C:/VenvPython36/Scripts/python.exe

import os
os.environ['PATH_INFO'] = '192.168.0.8/path/fake'
print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n") # Standard header

print('Hello')
```

No error is returned, however when I go to `192.168.0.8/path/fake` I get a `The requested URL was not found on this server` error.

Running `print(os.environ['PATH_INFO'])` does return `192.168.0.8/path/fake` as expected.

How can I make the server pass this to the url so that I can hide the path?

(I am trying to reproduce what `app.route()` does in Flask)